# Express JS sessionstore fails with android

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, xmlhttprequest, express

Well i was making a comet server [for the sake of learning] using express.js

for user authentication i used the session support with express..

But when i tested the app on Android it failed to load/store session objects..

Which makes an infinite loop of authentication.. on my client and which floods the server with 100s of request..

Further i stack traced the bug and found out that the cookies are intact so where is things going wrong ????

Android issue or Express JS issue ?? !??!?!

Because the thing works pretty stable on browsers like Chrome & Firefox and even IE

Comment: As a weirder thing the cookies are stored but express js fails to retrieve them because the server can read the cookies but fails to authenticate the client

Comment: Epic fail on my side.. the phone was set to future .. crappy Service Provider Values... aargghh i have been tearing my hairs out fr this :@